How to configure the brackets editor so that it displays the maximum number of columns allowed in the editor
I am using Brackets Release 2.2.0-17942 installed on MacBook Air. The same version was working correctly and could edit a file with the maximum number of columns, and could display the file with the source code with the maximum width of the editor's editing window. I had the need to perform a restart on the Macbook Air. When the MacBook Air rebooted, a screen was displayed asking if I wanted to save a Brackets configuration file (I don't remember what file or what options) after choosing to save the configurations, I am not allowed to edit the file with the maximum width allowed by the editing screen (as can be seen in the screenshot).

How can I configure the Brackets editor to be able to view the file being edited with the maximum number of columns allowed by the editing screen? I have tried several configurations, but I still don't have the result I want. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

The bracket editor configuration was resolved using the following link 12 Brackets Extensions That Will Make Your Life Easier which recommends the extensions for development. Following the instructions the problem was solved. Basically install all the recommended extensions. Except for the extensions (Simple To-Do) that are not available in my version of Brackets, and the extension (JS CSS Minifier) ​​that had an error during installation. Otherwise the editor is working as it should for what I need.

It is possible that some extensions could not be installed since for development I have macOS Sierra Version 10.12.6 (an older version of Mac OS that runs on MacBook Air), and the version of Brackets I have is Release 2.2 build 2.2 .0-17942


